# Fuzzy matching without 'master table'

Tags: r, fuzzy-logic, stringdist

Is it possible to perform some type of fuzzy matching without having a table of desired results?

For example, standardising these rows:

```
Lord Philip Harris
Lord Harris of Peckham
Lord Philip C. Harris
Philip Lord C Harris
Lord Phillip Harris of Peckham
```

into the first value, the last value or something like 'Philip Harris' - it doesn't really matter which.

I've used the stringdist package in R to append a column to a dataframe containing the value that's the minimum distance from the test but to do this, I had a list of 'correct' data.

Thanks

Comment: You may check `phonics` `soundex` function or `stringdist`

Comment: Hi, thanks. I've used stringdist but does it not require a comparison list as one of the arguments? I'll take a look at the others